# Concentration index in Python

Tags: python, r, inequality

I am estimating successful Concentration Index into programming language R with IC2 package. Below you can see function and results

```
library(IC2)
data(hhbudgets)
calcSConc(hhbudgets[, "transporte"], hhbudgets[,"ingreso"], param=0.5)

$ineq
$ineq$index
     SConc 
-0.6670986 

$ineq$parameter
param 
  0.5 

$nas
$nas$xNA
[1] 0

$nas$yNA
[1] 0

$nas$wNA
NULL

$nas$totalNA
[1] 0

attr(,"class")
[1] "ICI"
```

Now I want to apply the same function but into Python programming language.I found several packages such as concentrationMetrics and Ineqpy but I can find the same function.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?